# Define A Function In A "Class" And Call It To Print Array Elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a defined class "Automobiles" and I need add a function that accepts a boolean argument and produces output based on the input. My thought was to define the function in the Automobile class:

```
function Automobile(year, make, model, type) {
    this.year = year; //integer (ex. 2001, 1995)
    this.make = make; //string (ex. Honda, Ford)
    this.model = model; //string (ex. Accord, Focus)
    this.type = type; //string (ex. Pickup, SUV)

    function logMe(boolAnswer) {
        if (boolAnswer == true) {
            console.log(this.year + ' ' + this.make + ' ' + this.model + ' ' + this.type);
        } else {
            console.log(this.year + ' ' + this.make + ' ' + this.model);
        }
    };

}

var automobiles = [
    new Automobile(1995, "Honda", "Accord", "Sedan"),
    new Automobile(1990, "Ford", "F-150", "Pickup"),
    new Automobile(2000, "GMC", "Tahoe", "SUV"),
    new Automobile(2010, "Toyota", "Tacoma", "Pickup"),
    new Automobile(2005, "Lotus", "Elise", "Roadster"),
    new Automobile(2008, "Subaru", "Outback", "Wagon")
];
```

Then sort the automobiles and print the sorted array by calling:

```
var newArray = sortArr(yearComparator, automobiles);

newArray.forEach(logMe(true));
```

However, when I do this it says logMe is not defined. Do I need to change how I am defining logMe and make it a prototype? I'm confused how this function should be defined within Automobiles?

Comment: you have defined logMe inside the constructor

Comment: Move the `logMe` outside of the `Automobile`

Comment: It's an horrible idea to have a `logMe` method on a business object. I understand that's for learning purposes, but logging has nothing to do with automobiles. Data structures should be free of infrastructure concerns.

Comment: @plalx I agree, `toString` would've been better.

Answer (score 0):

### Your method

You'd need to set the `logMe` as a property on `this`, just like with data:

```
this.logMe = function logMe(boolAnswer) {
```

And then the function still isn't available from outside. You'd need to actually get it from the value:

```
newArray.forEach((obj) => obj.logMe(true));
```

### Prototype

Alternatively, if you chose to use a `prototype` mechanism, you could've moved `logMe` outside of the constructor:

```
Automobile.prototype.logMe = function logMe() { ...
```

And then you *could* use it in `forEach` directly:

```
newArray.forEach(Automobile.prototype.logMe)
```

But if you want to pass a parameter, you'd need some more elaborate fiddling, so I'd just stay with the lambda.

### Remark

As **@plalx** pointed out, the `logMe` function doesn't belong here. If anything, `toString` would've been a better choice; then you can use that value to actually log the object.